# Probability of an event

Tags: functions, probability-or-statistics, random

I am wondering if there is a way in Mathematica, a special function perhaps, which would return true or false based on a certain probability I give it. Like Prob[0.7] would return 1: 70% of the time and 0: 30% of the time. I could do something like this of course:

```
prob=10; (* 1% chance *)
val = RandomInteger[{1, 1000}];
If[val<= prob, True, False];
```

But this becomes slightly difficult when I need very specific probabilities like 0.21321312444. Or even variable probabilities which would come from a certain function returning different values every time step.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Clear[prob]

prob[p_, n : _Integer : 1] := RandomChoice[{p, 1 - p} -> {1, 0}, n]

Total[prob[0.21321312444, 10^5]]/10.^5.

(*  0.21322  *)
```

Answer (score 16):

Using built-in statistical functions ([Discrete Univariate Distributions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DiscreteUnivariateDistributions.html)).

```
sampleBernoulli[p_, n_] := RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[p], n]
```

Then

```
sampleBernoulli[.7, 10]
(* {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1} *)
```

Hope this helps.